# Method to return date ranges of 1 year

Tags: c#, datetime

I made a method that takes 2 `DateTime`s as a parameter, a `startDate` and a `stopDate`.

The routine should return a list of `DateTime` ranges by checking if the range in the parameters is above one year `TimeSpan`. If it is, it should separate the range into smaller ranges of one year, starting form `startDate` and adding a year until reaching the limit, and then adjusting the last range accordingly (as it might only contain a few months).

Can this method be made better or even recursive?

```
// startDate = 2016-01-01        
// endDate = 2020-06-01

List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> list = GetYearsBetweenDates(startDate, endDate);

//list = 2016-01-01 2016-12-31 
//       2017-01-01 2017-12-31 
//       2018-01-01 2018-12-31 
//       2019-01-01 2019-12-31 
//       2020-01-01 2020-06-01

private List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> GetYearsBetweenDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime stopDate)
{
    var list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>();
    var oneYear = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    var tempStopDate = startDate + oneYear;
    var tempStartDate = startDate;
    bool first = true;

    if (stopDate - startDate < oneYear)
    {
        list.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(startDate, stopDate));
        return list;
    }

    while (tempStopDate != stopDate)
    {
        list.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(tempStartDate, tempStopDate));
        if (first)
        {
            tempStartDate += oneYear.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)); // We should not have the same date twice
            first = false;
        }
        else
            tempStartDate += oneYear;

        tempStopDate += oneYear;

        if (tempStopDate > stopDate)
        {
            tempStopDate = stopDate;
            list.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(tempStartDate, stopDate));
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: A year is not 365 days long.

Comment: @RolandIllig True, but irrelevant for this question.

Comment: @Nicholas on the contrary, it produces an invalid end-date since the first leapyear in the range and it continues to grow every four years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you perform all calcuclations dynamically your method becomes a simple few lines long loop:

```
private IEnumerable<DateTimeRange> GetYearsBetweenDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime stopDate)
{
    for (int i = startDate.Year; i <= stopDate.Year; i++)
    {
        yield return new DateTimeRange
        (
            start: new DateTime(i, startDate.Month, startDate.Day),
            end:
             i == stopDate.Year 
             ? new DateTime(i, stopDate.Month, stopDate.Day).AddYears(1) 
             : new DateTime(i, startDate.Month, startDate.Day).AddYears(1)
        );
    }
}
```

So what I have I changed?

The method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and uses the `yield return` which makes it deferred (this means it is executed only if enumerated).

The `T` is a new `struct` that is easier to understand than a `Tuple`:

```
struct DateTimeRange
{
    public DateTimeRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }
    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime End { get; }
}
```

To get all dates you call it with `ToList` or `ToArray`

```
var dates = GetYearsBetweenDates(startDate, endDate).ToList();
```

or you put it in a `foreach` loop

```
foreach(var range in GetYearsBetweenDates(startDate, endDate))
{
    // do something
}
```

---

You can also exagerate and make it *pure* LINQ method without any *manual* loop but personaly I think the `for` loop looks better:

```
private IEnumerable<DateTimeRange> GetYearsBetweenDates3(DateTime startDate, DateTime stopDate)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(startDate.Year, stopDate.Year - startDate.Year + 1)
        .Select(x => new DateTimeRange
        (
            start: new DateTime(x, startDate.Month, startDate.Day),
            end:
             x == stopDate.Year 
             ? new DateTime(x, stopDate.Month, stopDate.Day).AddYears(1) 
             : new DateTime(x, startDate.Month, startDate.Day).AddYears(1)
        ));
}
```

---

What else?

> ```
> var list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>();
> ```

You should always choose meaningful names for all variables. You did it well for the others. This could have been `results` or `dates`.

> ```
> var oneYear = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
> ```

It's safer to use the `AddYear(1)` method rather then hardcoding the number. Especially if you don't want to care about leapyears.

Comment: Upvoted, but not convinced about `DateTimespan`... what's wrong with [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Mat'sMug well, the `TimeSpan` has no beginning, it has only a duration but here you want to have Start & End points. Perhaps the `DateTimespan` isn't a perfect name but I couldn't come up with something better. I guess `DateTimeRange` would have been more appropriate.

Comment: Fair enough, that does justify it :)

Comment: I've renamed it to `DateTimeRange`.

Comment: @Nicholas you can ask Mat's Mug about merging accounts if you want to, if I'm correct you're also the user122455, right?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I just told Nicholas you could merge his accounts if he wants to.

Comment: @Nicholas I've requested the merge to the community team, shouldn't take too long.